# Using css to slide elements when filling empty space

Tags: html, css, transition

I have several blocks of content. I slide one off to the side, then remove it. Once that is done, I want the blocks below it to slide up and take its place.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FTH7m/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="elem1" class="item one">
        Element 1
    </div>
    <div id="elem2" class="item two">
        Element 2
    </div>
    <div id="elem3" class="item three">
        Element 3
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.one {
    background-color: red;    
}

.two {
    background-color: blue;
}

.three {
    background-color: green;
}

.item {
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.closed {
    -webkit-transition: all .75s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .75s ease;
    -o-transition: all .75s ease;
    transition: all .75s ease;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-left: 200px;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

**Javascript/JQuery**

```
$('.item').on('click', function(){
    $(this)
    .addClass('closed')
    .on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd', function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

What transition can I uses so that if I click the red block, once it is removed the blue and green blocks will slide into place?

Comment: use `slidUp('slow')` instead of `remove()` then on complete of the slide up remove the element

Answer (score 1):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/FTH7m/2/)**

Give a try to this;

```
$(this).height(0).css({'margin':'0'});
```

or Probably this;

```
$(this).css({'margin':'0','height':'0'});
```

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can animate with height and margin equal to 0

```
$('.item').on('click', function(){
  var obj = $(this);
  $(this)
   .addClass('closed')
   .on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd', function(){
      obj.animate({ height: 0, margin : 0 }, 0);
   });
});
```

Here is the fiddle link **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FTH7m/5/)**

Comment: why is there such a massive delay?

Comment: @MirroredFate That was because of the second param of `animate` which should be set to 0 and I forgot. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.animate()` with time and adjust top or margin-top to move the element out of view.  Once out you can remove the element and reset the top / margin-top to its original value.